# Openstack nova mount volumes

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, large-data-volumes, volumes

I have one volume mounted as /vda, I created a new volume which is /vdb . Now when I mount this new volume I guess I can mount it to an existing directory on vda?? Hence growing the overall size of the existing directory ??

Comment: This is more of a general "how does Linux work" question than it is an OpenStack question. It's probably better off over on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

@larsks is correct.  This is mostly an operating systems question, and it would be better to ask on another site like ServerFault or Unix or AskUbuntu.

But since you are here, and since you asked in the context of Openstack, I'll answer here.

---

> Now when I mount this new volume I guess I can mount it to an existing directory on vda? Hence growing the overall size of the existing directory?

The short answer is No.  That's not how UNIX / Linux filesystems work.

When an Openstack Volume is *attached* to an Instance, it is viewed by the guest OS as a virtual disk device.  You then (typically) *format* it to contain a file system and *mount* the file system on top of a directory in the root file system.

(For a real physical disk, you normally *partition* the disk as well, and put the file systems into some of the partitions.  It is not normal practice to do that with an Volume.)

What you want here is a single file system that spans multiple Volumes; i.e. multiple virtual disks.  This is possible if you use Linux LVM (see https://opensource.com/business/16/9/linux-users-guide-lvm).  However, it is not possible to do an in-place conversion of an existing ordinary device into an LVM; see https://serverfault.com/questions/241987/convert-full-hard-drive-to-lvm-without-external-storage.

You probably need to do something like this:

1. Read all about LVM ... and decide if you can deal with the extra complexity.
2. Back up all your data!!
3. Attach your new Volume to the Instance.
4. Format it with LVM, and create a LVM volume on it and format the volume.
5. Mount the volume.
6. Copy the file system from your existing Volume into the new file system
7. Unmount file systems for the old volume and the new volume
8. Add the old volume into LVM and make it part of the existing LVM volume
9. Resize the file system so that it can use all of the space in the combined LVM volume.
10. Mount the file system.

If you have a file system split over two Volumes, your data integrity will depend on both of them.  I think you are better off either using the two Volumes as separate filesystems or creating a single large Volume.  Did you know that you can resize a Volume in some circumstances?